# How to resolve the conflict between two layer labels?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, maplex

Despite the fact that all labels placement methods and styles was tried ArcMap still fails to resolve the conflict between two layers labels?

In my case, I have two layers (the built-up area) and (well-known sites). And I am using maplex engine I tried all placement and position changing procedures, but unfortunately the labels still have clashes between them as shown in the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use "Label offset" located in the second figure?

Answer (score 1):

You have Never Remove (place overlapping) enabled. This option makes sure the label is always shown on the map, even if it overlaps other labels.
Also, you are using a fixed position at the centre of the polygon. This gives Maplex fewer alternative label positions.
Try turning both of these options off and your labels should be placed without overlap.